# React.js, where to put google maps api queries?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, organization

I'm building a google maps app with React.js.

My instinct is to create separate file with an ES6 class to handle search queries - within the class there will be a function that returns the search result. I intend to call that function from within a React Component.

See the  component below for reference.

Should I move the code inside the findRoutes() and drawBoxes() methods to separate files? This is my first react app - want to learn how to best organize the code. Any tips are hugely appreciated.

```
var MapControl = React.createClass({
            getInitialState: function(){
                return {
                    originId: '',
                    destinationId: '',
                    radius: 1,
                    search: '',
                    map: {},
                    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
                }
            },
            handleFormSubmit: function(input){
                // Form Input
                // Call findRoutes() once setState is complete.
                this.setState({
                    originId: input.originId,
                    destinationId: input.destinationId,
                    radius: input.radius,
                    search: input.search
                }, this.findRoutes);

            },
            handleMapRender: function(map){
                // Intialized Google Map
                this.setState({map: map});
                directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                routeBoxer = new RouteBoxer();
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            },
            findRoutes: function(){
                var me = this;
                if (!this.state.originId || !this.state.destinationId) {
                    alert("findRoutes!");
                    return;
                }
                directionsService.route({
                    origin: {'placeId': this.state.originId},
                    destination: {'placeId': this.state.destinationId},
                    travelMode: this.state.travelMode
                }, _.bind(function(response, status){
                    if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        // me.response = response;
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
                        this.setState({
                            routes: response,
                            boxes: routeBoxer.box(path, this.state.radius)
                        },this.drawBoxes);
                    } else {
                        window.alert('Directions config failed due to ' + status);
                    }
                }, this));
            },
            drawBoxes: function(){
                var boxpolys = new Array(this.state.boxes.length);
                for (var i = 0; i < this.state.boxes.length; i++) {
                    boxpolys[i] = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                        bounds: this.state.boxes[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0,
                        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                        strokeColor: '#000000',
                        strokeWeight: 1,
                        map: this.state.map
                    });
                }
            },
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="MapControl">
                        <h1>Search</h1>
                        <MapForm
                            onFormSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit}
                            map={this.state.map}/>
                        <GMap
                            setMapState={this.handleMapRender}
                            originId= {this.state.originId}
                            destinationId= {this.state.destinationId}
                            radius= {this.state.radius}
                            search= {this.state.search}/>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your instinct is correct, in general it's good practice to keep your view code as minimal as possible, and to move anything that is not explicitly related to rendering your view into another class.

React.js itself is not opinionated as to how you handle the rest of your application needs but a few libraries have emerged as the leading solutions for handling events, routing, services, data, etc.

You should review the Flux pattern for an overview of how you might manage the rest of your applications needs for React apps.
https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html

I've moved on from Flux to using Redux recently 
http://redux.js.org/ (which has emerged as the leading 'Fluxish' state management lib)

If you want to just get something up and running quickly and aren't trying to dive into all that just yet, I'd move the `findRoutes` method to an external `service` that you import in... `drawBoxes` seems fine to keep in here as it is directly related to rendering map elements in the view